# Jedis Issue - "Failed to connect to any host resolved for DNS name."

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, redis

Whenever I try to connect to my Redis server from my Java application using Jedis, I get `JedisConnectionException: Failed to connect to any host resolved for DNS name.` The Java application runs on the same machine as the Redis server.

When I check the Redis server's status using `systemctl`, it's online and running without problems. I also connected to the Redis client via terminal using command-line on the Linux machine it is running on, authenticated and performed `PING` in which `PONG` was returned to make sure the Redis was up running.

**Redis configuration**

I have bind and requirepass un-commented in the `redis.conf` and looks like following (not my entire config, of course):

```
bind 127.0.0.1
requirepass mypassword
port 6379
```

**This is the code I am using:**

```
private void setupRedis(RedisCredentials credentials) {
    final GenericObjectPoolConfig<Jedis> poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(0);

    Jedis jedis;
    try (JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, credentials.getIp(), credentials.getPort())) { 
        jedis = pool.getResource();
    }

    jedis.auth(credentials.getPassword());
    jedis.connect();
    log.info("Redis connection was established.")
}
```

I am a bit new to working with Redis therefor I wasn't sure on how much information to include in my post. All and any help is very much appreciated!

**Tried**

I tried the following code provided above multiple times. I have also tried restarting the Redis server and running the code again, with no successful try.

**Expected to happen**

For the application to log "*Redis connection was establish*" and to receive no errors in the process.

**Resulted**

The console logs the `redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed to connect to any host resolved for DNS name` and the application therefore obviously does not managed to establish a connection to Redis.

Comment: Please provide full stacktrace including all caused by blocks and suppressed blocks.

Comment: What IP and port are you using in the Java code? `bind 127.0.0.1` in your Redis config means Redis will only listen on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @SimonPrickett I have solved the issue and I was was simply binding to the wrong IP... I thought binding to 127.0.0.1 would be like binding to localhost (and seeing the redis server and the application connection to Redis runs on the same machine) that would work, but is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake. If I checked the open ports looks like 6379 is open but can't connect.

I recomend check the firewall. And on the case open the port there.

> ufw allow 6379

Answer (score 0):

For redis-cluster user this problem can happen if some of the master nodes are not up and running.